# Balanced Output on mixer to Unbalanced Input on another mixer

Tags: sound, mixing, setup, mixer

Can I safely take the L/R stereo mix (using two balanced 1/4" TRS connectors) out of one mixer into unbalanced inputs (two 1/4" unbalanced TS connectors) on a second mixer?

**Options**

1. Use two 1/4" TS unbalanced cables
2. Use two 1/4" TRS balanced cables

As usual Google is full of threads about this but they all talk about connecting to an amplifier. Given I'm going from mixer to mixer I wondered if I need to consider anything extra.

Comment: A TRS cable can transmit two channels out of a single output if the output is designed to be used that way.  For example a single headphone jack on a monitor or any other device usually transmit both left and right stereo channels through a TRS cable.  If the LR stereo mix is transmitted via two outputs then there is no need for a TRS cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that you are really dealing with unbalanced inputs on the second mixer: that's kind of unusual.  Note that balanced TRS inputs can be used just fine with unbalanced TS cables, so a working use with unbalanced source does not really mean that the input is unbalanced.

Only if you are very sure that the inputs are really unbalanced TS inputs, use TS cables.  Otherwise TRS cables will yield better results.